# Customize frappe framework html layout

Tags: python, frameworks, erpnext, frappe

ERPNext + frappe need to change layout(footer & header) front-end. I tried to change base.html(frappe/templates/base.html) but nothing happened. Probably this is due to the fact that the html files need to somehow compile. Maybe someone have info how to do it?

**UPDATE:**

**No such command "clear-cache".**

Commands:
  backup
  backup-all-sites
  config
  get-app
  init
  migrate-3to4
  new-app
  new-site
  patch
  prime-wheel-cache
  release
  restart
  set-default-site
  set-mariadb-host
  set-nginx-port
  setup
  shell
  start
  update

Comment: what is the version of bench and frappe?

Answer (score 0):

`bench clear-cache` will clear the cache. After doing this, refresh and check.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're not in your bench folder.

When you create a new bench with, for example : `bench init mybench` it creates a new folder : mybench.

All bench commands must be run from this folder.

Could you try to run `bench --help` in this folder ? You should see the `clear-cache` command.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone stumbles on this.  The command needed is **bench build**.  That will compile any assets related to the build.json file in the public folder.  (NOTE: You usually have to create build.json yourself).